# from pandas_profiling import profilereport Error

Tags: jupyter-notebook, python-3.10, pandas-profiling

I've installed the pandas_profiling package but, the system is not recognizing the package.

I'm using VS Code for the project.

Hi, I'm trying to install pandas profiling for an ML testing project I've checked multiple Question Related to it on StackOverFlow but could not find any match Or Solution.

I've checked the package and it got successfully installed on the system.

[image]

But I'm still getting the Error

[image]

FYI:
I've installed multiple packages required for the project, such as NumPy, pandas, etc., and did not face any problems.

Note: If any other info is required let me Know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

import sys
!{sys.executable} -m pip install pandas-profiling

Add the above line to the top of your file

Comment: import sys and !(sys) are supposed to be in a separate line.